# Powershell script for catching exception for adding group members to local group

Tags: powershell

I want to add members in Remote Desktop Users group and if i find "The specified account name is already a member of the group" exception then skip and move to other member to add.

I have tried below but it didnt catch the exception and keep giving me same error.. Please advice.

```
$LocalGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername/Remote Desktop Users,group" 
$DomainGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://Domain/Test Success Team" 

$LocalGroup.Add($DomainGroup.path)


Try {

$LocalGroup.Add($DomainGroup.path)

} Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException] {
    if ($_ -like "The specified account name is already a member of the group.") 
    {
        Write-Host “!!! LOCAL GROUP ALREADY EXISTS !!!”
    } 
    elseif ($_ -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host " lOCAL GROUP CREATED SUCCESSFULLY "
    }
```

**I am getting below error...**

```
    Exception calling "add" with "1" argument(s): "The specified account name is already a 
member of the group.
"
At line:4 char:1
+ $LocalGroup.Add($DomainGroup.path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI

Unable to find type [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException].
At line:11 char:9
+ } Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException] {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Activ...ent.ADException:TypeN 
   ame) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException]` is not a type known to the current session. Remove the type from the `catch` block and identify the true exception type name with `$_.GetType().FullName` inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I woulduse $($Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message) insted $_

```
if($($Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message).Contains("The specified account name is already a member of the group."))
```